# Trouble Migrating all data blog from Wordpress.com to Wordpress.org

Tags: database, mysql, errors, migration, blog

I'm transferring a WordPress.com blog to a new WordPress.org website but I'm having trouble transferring everything. I've gone through the usual WordPress tools - export XML file, import using the standard WordPress import tool under "Tools" - but not everything is carrying over.

One thing I had to do was run the import several times just to get all the POSTS carried over, but that stopped working and things like categories and tags aren't migrating, at least not 100%.

I also get this database error:

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object 
given in /home/rlp/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1129
```

I hesitate to post a link to the sites as I'm not sure if my client would allow this, so I'm only going to post it if someone deems it necessary to troubleshoot the issue.

Thanks very much.

Comment: How many posts are we talking about? Are the error only while importing posts or page and custom posts as well?

Comment: Only when importing posts. And there are hundreds of posts, going back a couple years. I'm only importing blog posts. It was only used as a blog, not a website.

Comment: Strange, but I've just noted that you mentioned WordPress.org website, I assume that you're migrating to a server outside WordPress.com platform. If that's the case, what is the version of WordPress and which host are you using? This database error is strange because it should not occur in a migration of WP to WP, but having to import more than one time means that your new server is limiting execution time

Comment: Correct, it's an outside server. The version of WP is the latest. The server is limiting execution time? This isn't my server, it's the client's server. I didn't even do the install of Wordpress, they did. How would I go about finding out what the execution time is and change that if needed?

Comment: You may try insert the code `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` inside wp-config.php, it will increase the execution time, but some servers limit it. If that's the problem it will show on the error log of the server.

Comment: If you import from local or http URL, its not import because wordpress.com only allow to https url for media export and import to your WordPress.